# Function for calculating the determinant of a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, determinants

I want my function to calculate the determinant of input Matrix A using row reduction to convert A to echelon form, after which the determinant should just be the product of the diagonal of A.
I can assume that A is an n x n np.array

This is the code that I already have:

```py
def determinant(A):
    A = np.matrix.copy(A)
    row_switches = 0
    #  Reduce A to echelon form
    for col in range(A.shape[1]):
        if find_non_zero(A, col) != col:
            #  Switch rows
            A[[find_non_zero(A, col), col], :] = A[[col, find_non_zero(A, col)], :]
            row_switches += 1
        #  Make all 0's below "pivot"
        for row in range(col+1, A.shape[0]):
            factor = A[row, col] / A[col, col]
            A[row, :] = A[row, :] - factor * A[col, :]

    return A.diagonal().prod() * (-1) ** row_switches


# Find first non-zero value starting from diagonal element
def find_non_zero(A, n):
    row = n
    while row < A.shape[0] and A[row, n] == 0:
        row += 1
    return row
```

I then compare my results with np.linalg.det(A). The difference is manageable for random matrices of floats below 50x50 (2.8e-08 difference), but after 70x70, the difference is between 1000 and 10'000 on average.
What could be the cause of this?

The other problem I have with my code is that for a Matrix of ints `A = np.random.randint(low=-1000,high=1000,size=(25, 25))`, the difference is even more insane:

1820098560 (mine) vs 1.0853429659737294e+81 (numpy)

Comment: Could you edit your question to show us `find_non_zero`?

Comment: @Reti43Totally forgot to include it, see the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues with integer arrays and you can address them by changing the first line of your function to `A = np.matrix(A, dtype=float)`.

1. You risk overflowing and throwing off your results completely.

```
>>> np.arange(1, 10).prod() # correct
362880
>>> np.arange(1, 20).prod() # incorrect
109641728
>>> np.arange(1, 20, dtype=float).prod() # correct
1.21645100408832e+17
```

2. Whatever the result of the rhs in the line `A[row, :] = A[row, :] - factor * A[col, :]` will be, it will be cast to an integer.

```
>>> a = np.zeros((3,), dtype=int)
>>> a[0] = 2.4
>>> a
array([2, 0, 0])
```

As for the inaccuracies with float arrays, **you have to live with them** because of floating arithmetic's limited precision. When the product of the diagonals gives you a number like 6.59842495617676e+17 and numpy gives 6.598424956176783e+17, you can see the results are very close. But they can only represent so many digits and when the number is very large, just a difference in the last couple of digits really means a difference in the 1000s. This will only get worse the bigger your matrices, and as a result the bigger your numbers. But in terms of relative difference, i.e., `(your_method - numpy) / numpy`, it's fairly good regardless the magnitude of the numbers you work with.

---

### Stability of the algorithm

A point about your `factor` value when it's very small from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination):

> One possible problem is numerical instability, caused by the possibility of dividing by very small numbers. If, for example, the leading coefficient of one of the rows is very close to zero, then to row-reduce the matrix, one would need to divide by that number. This means that any error existed for the number that was close to zero would be amplified. Gaussian elimination is numerically stable for diagonally dominant or positive-definite matrices. For general matrices, Gaussian elimination is usually considered to be stable, when using partial pivoting, even though there are examples of stable matrices for which it is unstable.[11]
>
> [snip]
>
> This algorithm differs slightly from the one discussed earlier, by choosing a pivot with largest absolute value. Such a partial pivoting may be required if, at the pivot place, the entry of the matrix is zero. In any case, choosing the largest possible absolute value of the pivot improves the numerical stability of the algorithm, when floating point is used for representing numbers.

If it matters, numpy uses [LAPACK's LU decomposition algorithm](https://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/dd/d9a/group__double_g_ecomputational_ga0019443faea08275ca60a734d0593e60.html) which implements an iterative version of Sivan Toledo's recursive LU algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, I totally overlooked that the copy on line 1 was still of type int. This solved the problem of the absurd differences with ints, but I still have a high difference with floats. I was aware of floating point inaccuracies, but didn't think they'd scale up to such a large number. You mentioned that `A[row, :] = A[row, :] - factor * A[col, :]` introduces problems due to floating point precision, but is there a fix for that? I can't think of any other way of reducing A to echelon form. Would switching rows help to choose "better" elements help?

Comment: @MarcMiller I've updated my answer to deal with the floating point aspect. While it is true that there are inaccuracies and they can lead problems, in general the algorithm is stable.

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort, I managed to improve my algorithm quite a bit by always switching the diagonal element with the largest absolute value below it. Also, the relative difference you mentioned seems a better indicator than the absolute difference I used in my testing so far. Do you think it would make sense to test for relative rather than absolute difference in my unittests?

Comment: @MarcMiller Since you can't represent all floats (even up to the decimal point) exactly, the absolute different is pointless. A double float has ~15 digits precision. So a number with 25 digits is represented like `x.<no more than 17 digits>e24`. Subtracting two such numbers from each other will give you an absolute error at least 1e8 big as the last 8 digits were never there as part of the information. The relative error tells you how close two numbers are in terms of how information they can capture, so if you expect to deal with numbers more than 15 digits long, then use the relative error.